# NSMutableArray sort with object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

i have a object with Type of NSObject contains "posts" object type of NSMutableArray. that post object has ID property.

MyObject.posts.post.ID = NSInteger;

I want to sort "posts" NSMutableArray by ID. i have tried couple ways but couldn't be success.
any help/sample would be great.

thank you.

Comment: Could you please post some code of the things you tried? It is usually much easier to pinpoint problems in your code than to write something up from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a compare method, or use NSSortDescriptor.

This question and the answer may helps you.

[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: Please don't simply post links to other questions as answers. Leave a comment and flag this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an array with a block using `NSComparator` ([NSComparator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html))

Definition of -sortedArrayUsingComparator: found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a)

```
MyObject.posts = [MyObject.posts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
  if (obj1.post.ID > obj2.post.ID)
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
  if (obj1.post.ID < obj2.post.ID)
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
  return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```